# Rails: Instance variable seems to be empty on Heroku, not locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In my Rails app, I define a function in my Pages controller that uses Nokogiri to scrape a site for players and their rankings.  This function then sorts them and puts the results into an array, which I store in my @ladder instance variable.

Then in the /ladder view, I loop through @ladder and create an ordered list.  This happens on my local version but, on my Heroku version it displays nothing.  This makes me think the instance variable is empty.

When I throw a binding.pry into my local version, the instance variable isn't empty (as expected, since the ladder page renders properly and shows the list).

For reference, here are my Heroku logs:

```
2013-10-11T21:11:38.843027+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2013-10-11T21:11:38.848890+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (1.7ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:38.852468+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (1.1ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:38.853645+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:38.853645+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:38.852468+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (1.1ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:38.853968+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 9.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:38.843027+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2013-10-11T21:11:38.848890+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (1.7ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:38.853968+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 9.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:39.062593+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-52afa7d9057584fe39fc9ea4de80358e.js host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="75.69.249.248" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=91ms status=200 bytes=916227
2013-10-11T21:11:38.863375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="75.69.249.248" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=396ms status=200 bytes=1485
2013-10-11T21:11:46.332091+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/knitting250px.png" for 75.69.249.248 at 2013-10-11 21:11:46 +0000
2013-10-11T21:11:46.332091+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/knitting250px.png" for 75.69.249.248 at 2013-10-11 21:11:46 +0000
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333297+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/knitting250px.png"):
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333297+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333297+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333297+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333297+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333297+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333297+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333297+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333297+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333297+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333794+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333794+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333794+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333794+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/knitting250px.png"):
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333794+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333794+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333794+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333794+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333794+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.333794+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334611+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334611+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.334611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-10-11T21:11:46.335639+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/knitting250px.png host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="75.69.249.248" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=728
2013-10-11T21:11:48.920310+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="75.69.249.248" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-10-11T21:11:51.323199+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/ladder" for 75.69.249.248 at 2013-10-11 21:11:51 +0000
2013-10-11T21:11:51.325258+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#ladder as HTML
2013-10-11T21:11:51.323199+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/ladder" for 75.69.249.248 at 2013-10-11 21:11:51 +0000
2013-10-11T21:11:51.325258+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#ladder as HTML
2013-10-11T21:11:51.379144+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:51.377692+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/ladder.html.haml within layouts/application (2.2ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:51.378952+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:51.378952+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:51.377692+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/ladder.html.haml within layouts/application (2.2ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:51.379442+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 5.5ms | ActiveRecord: 28.7ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:51.379442+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 5.5ms | ActiveRecord: 28.7ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:51.379144+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-10-11T21:11:51.381483+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ladder host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="75.69.249.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=61ms status=200 bytes=1333
2013-10-11T21:11:28.381521+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2013-10-11T21:11:28.381827+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
```

Thanks in advance!

-Mariogs

P.S. Logs after adding "p @ladder" to controller method:

```
This is what I get in my logs after doing that:2013-10-11T22:43:49.549870+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/ladder" for 75.69.249.248 at 2013-10-11 22:43:49 +0000
2013-10-11T22:43:49.551511+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#ladder as HTML
2013-10-11T22:43:49.559624+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/ladder.html.haml within layouts/application (0.7ms)
2013-10-11T22:43:49.561786+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-10-11T22:43:49.551511+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#ladder as HTML
2013-10-11T22:43:49.549870+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/ladder" for 75.69.249.248 at 2013-10-11 22:43:49 +0000
2013-10-11T22:43:49.559624+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/ladder.html.haml within layouts/application (0.7ms)
2013-10-11T22:43:49.561786+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-10-11T22:43:49.562004+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2013-10-11T22:43:49.562004+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2013-10-11T22:43:49.562350+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 5.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
2013-10-11T22:43:49.562350+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 5.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

Controller Code:

```
  def ladder
    if Ladder.exists?
      @ladder = Ladder.all.first
    else
      get_most_recent_ladder
    end
  end

  def get_most_recent_ladder
    @top_80 = Team.all
    # loop through all teams, add each player and their rating to the hash, sort by rating, limit to 200
    all_players = {}

    @top_80.each do |team|
      url = "http://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/Team_Information.asp?id=#{team.team_id}"
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
      player_names = doc.css('.table.table-bordered.table-striped.table-condensed')[1].css('tr td a').map(&:content)
      player_ratings = doc.css('.table.table-bordered.table-striped.table-condensed')[1].css('tr td:nth-child(4)').map(&:content)
      team_players_hash = {}
      for i in (0..player_names.length-1)
          team_players_hash[player_names[i]] = player_ratings[i].to_f
      end
      all_players = all_players.merge(team_players_hash)
    end

    all_players = all_players.sort_by{|_key, value| value}.reverse.first(200)
    list = []
    all_players.each do |player|
      list << player[0]
    end
    #insert creation of ladder object with order
    @ladder = Ladder.create(order: list)
    render 'ladder'
    p @ladder
  end
```

View Code:

```
#ladder
  %ol
    -@ladder.order.each do |l|
      %li
        = l
```

Comment: Try to debug app on heroku: just add "p @ladder" to the controller method and look the logs again after page reloading.

Comment: See above for what I get in my logs after doing that

Comment: Seems nothing has changed. Write the view and controller code.

Comment: updated above (controller and view code)!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, `p @ladder` doesn't fire, cause `Ladder.exists?` is true.

Are you sure the table on heroku is not empty?

Try `heroku run console` and then `Ladder.all.first`